# Как добавлять/удалять items в MutableStateFlow(List<Int>) и потом использовать этот List<Int> как аргумент в Dao-запросе? Где у меня ошибка?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, viewmodel, coroutine

У меня в базе 1000 объектов Word поделенных на 17 категорий. Мне нужно чтобы в выпадающем меню пользователь отмечал категории, которые нужно отображать в recyclerView. Для этого в меню item-ы с чекбоксами:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_filter_by_categories"
    android:title="Filter by categories"
    app:showAsAction="never">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/action_cat1" android:title="@string/topic_at_home" android:checkable="true" />
        <item android:id="@+id/action_cat2" android:title="@string/topic_food" android:checkable="true" />
        <item android:id="@+id/action_cat3" android:title="@string/topic_wears" android:checkable="true" />
        // и так далее до 17
    </menu>
</item>
```

Мне нужно чтобы каждый чекБокс добавлял Int соответствующего номера категории в специальный List, который будет аргументом в dao+запросе (запрос см.ниже). Проблема что я вызываю dao-запрос методом wordsFlow(), который комбинирует аргументы как MutableStateFlow-ы, а в таком виде в аргумент я не могу добавлять/удалять значения как в List. См ниже что происходит во ViewModel.
Вобщем мне надо как-то менять содержимое List categoryList, чекая/анчекая item-ы в popup меню.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

in Dao:

```
    fun getWords(query: String, sortOrder: SortOrder, categoryList: List<Int>): Flow<List<Word>> =
        when(sortOrder) {
            SortOrder.BY_CATEGORY -> getWordsSortedByCategory(query, categoryList)
            SortOrder.BY_FOREIGN -> getWordsSortedByForeign(query,categoryList)
        }

    @Query("SELECT * FROM word_table WHERE category IN (:categoryList) AND (`nativ` LIKE '%' || :searchQuery || '%' OR `foreign` LIKE '%' || :searchQuery || '%') ORDER BY category ASC")
    fun getWordsSortedByCategory(searchQuery: String, categoryList: List<Int>): Flow<List<Word>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM word_table WHERE category IN (:categoryList) AND (`nativ` LIKE '%' || :searchQuery || '%' OR `foreign` LIKE '%' || :searchQuery || '%') ORDER BY `foreign` ASC")
    fun getWordsSortedByForeign(searchQuery: String, categoryList: List<Int>): Flow<List<Word>>
```

In ViewModel:

```
val searchQuery = MutableStateFlow("")
val sortOrder = MutableStateFlow(SortOrder.BY_CATEGORY)
val categoryList = MutableStateFlow(arrayListOf(Int)) // ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ НЕ ПОЙМУ КАК СДЕЛАТЬ List<Int> так, чтобы в него добавлять/удалять Ints

private val wordsFlow = combine(
    searchQuery,
    sortOrder,
    categoryList
) { query, sortOrder, categoryList ->
    Triple(query, sortOrder, categoryList)
}.flatMapLatest { (query, sortOrder, categoryList) ->
    wordDao.getWords(query, fsortOrder, categoryList ) // here is an error: Type mismatch.
// Required: List<Int> Found: kotlin.collections.ArrayList<Int.Companion>
}

val words = wordsFlow.asLiveData()

fun addCategory(catNum: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
    categoryList.// не могу написать .add добавить в List, error "unresolved reference", ".add" подсвечена красным
}
```

In the Fragment:

```
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_sort_by_foreign -> {
                viewModel.sortOrder.value = SortOrder.BY_FOREIGN
                true
            }
            R.id.action_sort_by_category -> {
                viewModel.sortOrder.value = SortOrder.BY_CATEGORY
                true
            }
            R.id.action_cat1 -> {
                item.isChecked = !item.isChecked
                viewModel.addCategory(1)
                true
            }
            R.id.action_cat2 -> {
            ///bla bla bla and so on for 17 categories.
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`categoryList` это не `ArrayList`, а `MutableStateFlow`. Получить значение из `MutableStateFlow` можно через `value` свойство. Но это всё равно не поможет, потому что для того, чтобы `MutableStateFlow` уведомил подписчиков об новом значении нужно установить это новое значение через `value` и оно должно отличаться от предыдущего (проверяется через `equals`).

В общем лучше всего сделать так:

```
val categoryList = MutableStateFlow(listOf<Int>())

fun addCategory(catNum: Int) {
   categoryList.value += catNum
}
```